# Binomial rearrangement

Tags: binomial-theorem

How is it possible to get this equality?  What can one do for this ?  I find it hard to see how starting from $k=1$ results in a binomial that has got $k-1$.

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} a^{n-k} b^{k+1} 
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1} a^{n-(k-1)} b^{(k-1)+1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They reindexed the summation. Starting with
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^{k+1},$$
set $l = k+1 \implies l-1 = k.$ When we index in terms of $l$, we are summing from $1$ to $n$. The lower index of the sum isn't notationally correct but I wrote it in to have it make sense.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^{k+1}
=
\sum_{l-1=0}^{(l-1=)n-1} \binom{n}{l-1}a^{n-(l-1)}b^{(l-1)+1}
=
\sum_{l=1}^n \binom{n}{l-1}a^{n+1-l}b^l.$$

Comment: How can one get the limits correct without your notationally incorrect addition ?

Comment: Ok, Have done it now,  All good,